# MySQL Error 1064 when using CASE trying to update a field in between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, case

I have two tables: projects and temp_projects ($table in code below). I'm using the following MySQL query to try and update a field on temp_projects using data from projects.

Here is the query:

```
    $this->q("UPDATE $table, projects
     CASE
        WHEN $table.$number_field != projects.number 
            THEN set $table.$id_field = projects.id WHERE $table.old_proj_num = projects.number
        WHEN $table.$number_field = projects.number
            THEN SET $table.$id_field = projects.id WHERE $table.$number_field = projects.number
     END");
```

The error I get is:

```
MySQL error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE
                    WHEN temp_projects.number != projects.number
                            THEN set temp_proj' at line 2
When executing:
UPDATE temp_projects, projects
             CASE
                    WHEN temp_projects.number != projects.number
                            THEN set temp_projects.project_id = projects.id WHERE temp_projects.old_proj_num = projects.number
                    WHEN temp_projects.number = projects.number
                            THEN SET temp_projects.project_id = projects.id WHERE temp_projects.number = projects.number
             END
```

The issues I'm having is the line in the error message "THEN set temp_proj' at line 2

After THEN it should read **THEN SET temp_projects.project_id = projects.id WHERE temp_projects.number = projects.number**.

I'm trying to figure out why it's cutting off the query after **THEN set temp_proj**

I'm not familiar with using the CASE command so any pointers would appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

make your query as below:

```
> UPDATE Students  
  SET NAME =  CASE  
>                         WHEN NAME = 'ABC' THEN 'MNO' 
>                         WHEN NAME = 'DEF' THEN 'JKL' 
>                         WHEN NAME = 'EFG' THEN 'GHI' 
>                         ELSE NAME
>      END  WHERE   LASTNAME IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'EFG')
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$this->q("UPDATE $table, projects
        set $table.$id_field =
        CASE
            WHEN $table.$number_field != projects.number 
                THEN projects.id WHERE $table.old_proj_num = projects.number
            WHEN $table.$number_field = projects.number
                THEN projects.id WHERE $table.$number_field = projects.number
        END");
```

My WHERE clause is different in both WHEN statements, I need to look for the data in a different spot depending if $table.$number_field and projects.number are equal or not.